# angularJS audio IE compatibility

Tags: angularjs, audio

I am trying to use html5 audio, and now it runs smoothly with chrome and firefox. I am having some problems with IE. In IE, when the audio is over, the play/pause button does not change. It still is the play icon, and what I want is to show the pause icon. My code is below:

```
<section ng-show="audio.canPlay">
    <a class="star" ng-show="audio.paused" ng-click='audio.play()'></a>
    <a class="star s-pause" ng-hide="audio.paused" ng-click='audio.pause()'></a>
</section>

var isProgessMove = false;
scope.clickPlayProgess = function (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    var now = (evt.offsetX / $(evt.target).parent().width());
    scope.audio.progress = (formatRange(now));
}
scope.mousedownPlayBar = function (evt) {
    isProgessMove = true;
    scope.lastScreenX = -($(evt.target).parent().width()) + evt.screenX;
    $(document).on('mousemove', movePlayPorgess);
    $(document).on('mouseup', mouseupProgessBar);
}
var movePlayPorgess = function (evt) {
    if (isProgessMove) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
            var now = (evt.screenX - scope.lastScreenX) / 398;
            scope.audio.progress = formatRange(now);
        })
    }
}
var mouseupPorgessBar = function () {
    isPorgessMove = false;
    $(document).off('mousemove');
    $(document).off('mouseup');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I know, That is because the ngaudio is not packaging "audio.ended",you can do it by yourself.

```
<section ng-show="audio.canPlay">
    <a class="star" ng-show="audio.paused || audio.audio.ended" ng-click='audio.play()'></a>
    <a class="star s-pause" ng-hide="audio.paused || audio.audio.ended" ng-click='audio.pause()'></a>
</section>
```